# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.1.3912.1204,

Tags: csom, assembly-references, filenotfoundexception

Previously I was using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll of version 15.0 in my application. I just removed that reference and added new reference of assembly of version 16.1. But now it is giving error: 
`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.1.3912.1204, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Click on assembly and press F4 to load its properties in Visual Studio. Try changing the value of Copy Local to true. And check if your project uses the latest .NET version.

Comment: Thanks... Did the same and also set the specific version property as 'True'. Problem is solved now.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on assembly and press F4 to load its properties in Visual Studio. Try changing the value of Copy Local to true. And check if your project uses the latest .NET version.