# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

I have this error using Visual Studio 2013. I have added the `Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll` and `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.dll`

Tried it on .Net Framework 4.0 and 4.5.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What reference do I need to add for this to work please?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint your are using ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to build? Are you trying to build something that lives inside of Sharepoint (like a Web Part) or are you trying to build an application that will communicate with SharePoint remotely?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150517/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sharepoint-client-version-16-1-3912

Comment: From which hive, have you added references of these DLLs?

Comment: Have the same problem by deploying a solution on a 2016 farm...